# How to deal with incompetent teaching?

Tags: teaching

I am doing a Master's programme that is a sort of mixture of linguistics and literature. The university is in Europe and is in the world's TOP 200 according to QS rankings.

I feel that most of the academic staff in the department is incompetent. They:

- make lots of factual errors in lectures and when grading tests;
- don't seem to understand the material they're presenting - the discussion in the seminars is superficial;
- give feedback and advice that is unhelpful and unsound;
- shut down my ideas in ways that makes me angry.

To make matters worse, it seems to me that none of my co-students is interested in academic work (at least in the topics we're covering). They hardly ever offer interesting input in seminars.

What should I do? I feel like I can't protest and criticise too loudly, because I am interested in pursuing academic career in that same university and don't want to hurt my reputation and relations.

Comment: You think most of the people there are incompetent and yet want to pursue your career in that place? I don’t feel you would be happy even if you manage to do so…

Comment: @Benjamin_Gal there is always the possibility of trying to bring about change for the better.

Comment: @Sursula How would the be possible if they don't want to report the problems for fear of it hurting them at the institution?

Comment: Criticize what? That no one is competent as you think? I can hardly imagine that this is the case in Europe but if you believe so, there is nothing to criticize, just run away!

Comment: @JoeW I guess once you are employed by the university as a lecturer/professor, you will be able to tackle problems without having to fear for your career as much. If you are already percieved as a troublemaker as a student, chances are you will not get hired in the first place.

Comment: @Sursula If addressing problems like that is considered being a trouble maker would they really bother fixing them just because a new professor says something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question asks "how to deal with ..."? As with so many similar questions, there really seem to be two parts that are easily conflated, as indeed is suggested by your own dot points.

One issue, which you list as the last (fourth) dot point, concerns matters internal to you; specifically, your own internal emotive response. The other issue, covered in the first two dot points, concerns things external to you: the "objective" (I use the term with some hesitancy) state or quality of the teaching. The third dot point is concerned with both internal and external issues.

With regard to the first issue, illustrated with "... in ways that ***make*** me angry", I suggest that crucial thing is to take responsibility for your own emotions and to recognize that while you might get *yourself* angry about things that you consider to be wrong, improper, unjust, incompetent etc. the causative agent in your anger is you and your own thoughts. If you doubt this, consider the possibility that you had never been to the university where you now are. Whatever teaching is currently takes place in your presence, would just as likely take place without you. And yet, if you were not there, you would not be getting angry! The teaching events themselves therefore cannot be the direct cause of your emotion. So, learn to manage your own emotions, perhaps by examining your own thinking processes. The teaching *might* be incompetent, but your emotive response is ***your*** response ... and your responsibility.

The second issue is how to deal with the quality of the teaching itself.

You ask what you *should* do, as if there is a moral imperative to do something at this time and in this place. There isn't! If you think there is, I would suggest that it is because you still haven't managed the issue about your emotions. Once you have reduced the question to the more realistic problem of "what, if anything, *could* I do to improve the quality of teaching" you might more clearly see the truth of many of the comments that have already been made! You might, for example, decide that anything you do would be too costly, or too unlikely to succeed, for you to make any attempt to improve things at all. Alternatively, you might, as another commenter suggests, simply complete the course you are doing, hope you are employed at the institution, and work for change from the inside.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are in a difficult situation and feeling frustrated with the quality of the education you are receiving. Here are a few suggestions for how you might proceed:

Talk to your advisor or department head: They may not be aware of the issues you're experiencing and may be able to address them. You can express your concerns in a respectful and constructive manner, highlighting specific examples and suggesting potential solutions.

Seek out other resources: Look for other professors or academic staff members who may be able to provide additional support or guidance. You might also consider reaching out to alumni or other students who have completed the program to gain their perspective.

Take advantage of office hours: If you are struggling with the material, consider visiting your professors during their office hours to ask for additional help.

Seek out additional support: If you are struggling with the coursework, you might consider finding a tutor or study group to help you stay on track.

Consider your options: If the situation does not improve and you feel like your academic progress is being hindered, it might be worth considering transferring to another program or university.

It is important to remember that, as a student, you have the right to a quality education, and it's okay to speak up if you feel that your needs are not being met. However, it's also important to be respectful and tactful in your communication, and consider the potential consequences of your actions. It is always a good idea to think before you act and make sure you are in the right frame of mind.